# Text not getting displayed while using canvas in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I am trying to achieve this on my webpage:

[image]

I have drawn the triangle using canvas ,that was successful but when I tried to put the text ,it is not getting displayed (also tried putting z-index).

This is the corresponding **[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nihar/J97H9/)**.

This is the html part

```
<section id="intro2" data-navigation-tag="Features" style="display: block; background-position: 50% 44.866px;">

    <canvas id="intro2canvas"></canvas>
    <div id="intro2content" class="content" style="z-index:100;">
        <div class="contentData"> 
            <span><h2>Celebrating<br/>the Past,<br/>Unveiling<br/>the Future</h2><span>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="intro2leftdiv"></div>-->
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;float:left;bottom:3%;left:4.5%;height:25%;width:34%;">
        <img src="innerimages/50yrs.png" width="100%" height="100%">
    </div>
</section>
```

How to do that ?

Comment: Why don't you add text using `fillText()` method?

Comment: I have tried that ,but can I use the .animate ()and .hide() as we use in javascript to show or hide a particular text.
That is the thing I will be implementing next

Comment: No you can't target specific canvas element

Comment: @ A.Wolff how to do that in this case ??

Comment: May be SVG instead of Canvas?

Comment: are you trying to this http://jsfiddle.net/J97H9/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create such effects using CSS only. In that case you'll be more flexible with the content. See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Tbtp/1/).

The idea is creating a triangle with the help of borders:

**CSS**:

```
.triangle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(242,91,32,0.45);
}
```

And a small piece of **JS**:

```
var triangle = document.getElementById('triangle'),
    triangleWidth = triangle.offsetWidth;
triangle.style.borderWidth = triangleWidth + 'px 0 0 ' + triangleWidth + 'px';
```

You can read more about this approach [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) and [here](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/).